# cv::imread image is not show on MFC's picture box

Tags: opencv, mfc

I'm building the dialog-based MFC application.
When I click the Button then I can choose the image from the file explorer and that image is also loaded into `cv::imread()`. And also shows in the Picture Control.

I can load and show an image in the Picture Control with the following code.

```
void CMFCApplication3Dlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
    cv::Mat src = cv::imread("D:/source/repos/Testing_Photos/Large/cavalls.png");
    Display(src);

}
```

But not with the following code.

```
void CMFCApplication3Dlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
    TCHAR szFilter[] = _T("PNG (*.png)|*.png|JPEG (*.jpg)|*.jpg|Bitmap (*.bmp)|*.bmp||");
    CFileDialog dlg(TRUE, NULL, NULL, OFN_HIDEREADONLY | OFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT, szFilter, AfxGetMainWnd());

    if (dlg.DoModal() == IDC_BUTTON1)
    {
        CString cstrImgPath = dlg.GetPathName();
        CT2CA pszConvertedAnsiString(cstrImgPath);
        std::string strStd(pszConvertedAnsiString);
        cv::Mat src = cv::imread(strStd);

        Display(src);
    }
}
```

And the following is the "Display" function.

```
void CMFCApplication3Dlg::Display(cv::Mat& mat) {

    CStatic * PictureB = (CStatic *)GetDlgItem(IDC_STATIC);

    CWnd* cwn = (CWnd *)GetDlgItem(IDC_STATIC);
    CDC* wcdc = cwn->GetDC();
    HDC whdc = wcdc->GetSafeHdc();

    RECT rec;
    cwn->GetClientRect(&rec);

    cv::Size matSize;
    matSize = cv::Size(rec.right, rec.bottom);

    BITMAPINFO bitmapinfo;

    bitmapinfo.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 24;
    bitmapinfo.bmiHeader.biWidth = mat.cols;
    bitmapinfo.bmiHeader.biHeight = -mat.rows;
    bitmapinfo.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    bitmapinfo.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    bitmapinfo.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    bitmapinfo.bmiHeader.biClrImportant = 0;
    bitmapinfo.bmiHeader.biClrUsed = 0;
    bitmapinfo.bmiHeader.biSizeImage = 0;
    bitmapinfo.bmiHeader.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
    bitmapinfo.bmiHeader.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;


    StretchDIBits(
        whdc,
        0, 0,
        matSize.width, matSize.height,
        0, 0,
        mat.cols, mat.rows,
        mat.data,
        &bitmapinfo,
        DIB_RGB_COLORS,
        SRCCOPY
    );

}
```

I am very new to MFC and I really don't have any idea where I'm wrong. 
Please help me! 
Thank you.

Comment: In order to debug this, you have to validate each substep.  1)  Did the `cv::Mat src` get loaded correctly, add instrumentation or view its members in the debugger.  2)  Is the `BITMAPINFO` being initialized correctly?  3)  Is the `StretchDIBits` being setup correctly?  You can find samples on MSDN or SO on how to use that structure with `StrechDIBits`.  4)  Check the return value of `StretchDIBits`, and possibly GetLastError (if the API actually uses).  5)  Does any other GDI drawing call work with those window values, like can you set a background color?  You might need WM_PAINT message?

Comment: As a general rule, rendering should always be done in response to receiving a `WM_PAINT` message. But since you already have `CStatic` control, you don't need to render anything. Just construct your image, and call [CStatic::SetBitmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cstatic-class#setbitmap). Rendering is subsequently handled by the control.

Answer (score 2):

This is not the correct method to paint. The picture will be erased every time there is a paint request.

That's what happens with `CFileDialog` which forces another repaint immediately after you paint the image. You have to respond to `OnPaint` or `OnDrawItem`, or use `CStatic::SetBitmap` as noted in comment.

You can do this with `CImage` class, there is no need for OpenCV:

```cpp
CImage img;
if(S_OK == img.Load(L"unicode.jpg"))
{
    CStatic *control = (CStatic*)GetDlgItem(IDC_STATIC);
    control->ModifyStyle(0, SS_BITMAP);
    auto oldbmp = control->SetBitmap(img.Detach());
    if(oldbmp)  
        DeleteObject(oldbmp);
}
```

Or you can use OpenCV to create `HBITMAP` handle.

Note that OpenCV does not handle Unicode filenames. `CW2A` converts Unicode to ANSI character encoding. This fails if one or more code points cannot be represented in the currently active code page. To work around it, we can open the file with `CFile` or `std::ifstream`, read it as binary, then open with `cv::imdecode` instead. Example:

```cpp
//open the file from unicode path:
const wchar_t *filename = L"unicode.jpg";
std::ifstream fin(filename, std::ios::binary);
if(!fin.good())
    return;

//read from memory
std::vector<char> vec(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(fin), {});
cv::Mat src = cv::imdecode(vec, cv::IMREAD_COLOR);
if(!src.data)
    return;

//create hbitmap
BITMAPINFOHEADER bi = { sizeof(bi), src.cols, -src.rows, 1, 24 };
CClientDC dc(this);
auto hbmp = CreateDIBitmap(dc, &bi, CBM_INIT, src.data, (BITMAPINFO*)&bi, 0);

//send hbitmap to control
auto control = (CStatic*)GetDlgItem(IDC_STATIC);
auto oldbmp = control->SetBitmap(hbmp);
if (oldbmp)
    DeleteObject(oldbmp);
```

Comment: `SetBitmap` transfers ownership of the current bitmap into the control, as well as the previous bitmap out of the control. The implementation doesn't seem to account for this, prematurely deleting the new bitmap, and potentially leaking the previous one. A simple fix is to use the following pattern: `img.Attach(control->SetBitmap(img.Detach()));`. This properly deals with the transfer of ownership in both directions.

Comment: @IInspectable yes my method was wrong, corrected it. `img.Attach(control->SetBitmap(img.Detach()))` won't work, because upon the first call to `SetBitmap`, it returns `NULL`, and `CImage::Attach` will throw Debug Assertion. We have to check the old bitmap before deleting it, or re-attaching to `CImage`

Comment: I wasn't aware, that `CImage::Attach()` would assert when passing a `nullptr`. After all, it does have a `CImage::Detach()` member, so not owning any resources seems to be a valid state.

Comment: @IInspectable Yes, it looks like a minor design flaw. They should have made the method accept `NULL` input.